# Find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces for the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces for the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4&2&2\\2&4&2\\2&2&4\end{bmatrix}$

I know there is a trick to this one with out doing a $3 \times 3$ determinant to find it's eigenvalues (which is horrendous in this case) (i.e: $i - j + k$)

I started with $\begin{bmatrix}4-\lambda&2&2\\2&4-\lambda&2\\2&2&4-\lambda\end{bmatrix}$ then thought it would be best to seek advice before going deep into the rabbit hole. Can I put this matrix into a form where the 2's are all 0s? What is this form called? And will that change my determinant? Because if I can do that, I can take the product of the diagonal and find my eigenvalues much easier!

Comment: What if you factor a $2$?

Comment: You can write your matrix as $2I+2X$ where all entries of $X$ are $1$. Since the rank of $X$ is $1$, its eigenvectors should be easy to find.

Comment: After I Get the determinant do I need to multiply it back by 2 again since i factored out a 2?

Comment: What? How does $2I + 2X$ help me? That just gives me a new matrix of $\begin{bmatrix}6&2&2\\2&6&2\\2&2&6\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Shammy all vectors are eigenvectors of the identity matrix. If you find the eigenvectors of 2X they will also be eigenvectors of 2I+2X due to the linearity of the operators. By the way you did not add 2I+2X correctly. X is a matrix with 1's in each entry, the result of 2I+2X should have 4's down the main diagonal and 2's in the off diagonal entries as in the matrix you began with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on stewbasic's comment: Your matrix can be decomposed as $2I + 2X$, where $X$ is simply filled with $1$s. We are looking for scalars $\lambda$ and vectors $v$ satisfying $$\lambda v = (2I+2X)v = 2v + 2Xv \iff (\lambda/2 - 1)v = Xv.$$

The eigenvalues of $X$ are easy to compute: the eigenvalues of any $n \times n$ matrix of rank $1$ are given by its trace (with multiplicity $1$), and zero (with multiplicity $n-1$). In this case the trace is $3$, and so we obtain the eigenvalues $\lambda = 3,0$, with respective eigenspaces spanned by $\{(1,1,1)\}$ and $\{(-1,0,1),(-1,1,0)\}$.

Therefore the corresponding eigenvalues for $2I + 2X$ are $2(3+1)=8$ and $2(0+1) = 2$, with the same eigenvectors as above.

Comment: The eigenvalues are not easy to compute at all for me. How exactly are you doing this? what is the matrix that you are taking the determinant of?

Comment: What are you doing to this matrix $\begin{bmatrix}4&2&2\\2&4&2\\2&2&4\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: What? How does $2I + 2X$ help me? That just gives me a new matrix of $\begin{bmatrix}6&2&2\\2&6&2\\2&2&6\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Shammy We reduced the problem to finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors for the matrix $X$ that is filled with $1$s. The eigenvalues of a rank $1$ matrix such as this are simply the trace (with multiplicity $1$) and zero (with multiplicity $n-1$).

Comment: @Shammy We are saying that the matrix you gave us is exactly the sum $2I + 2X$, where $X$ is a matrix filled with $1$s.

Comment: I just do not understand how you are computing the eigenvalues if you aren't taking the determinant.

Comment: Yea I'm really confused on what you've done here. First off, I am supposed to be doing $A - \lambda I$ right?

Comment: Where are you getting $\lambda = 3,0$ from?? what???

Comment: @Shammy There is an easy trick for computing the eigenvalues of a rank $1$ matrix, but you can find them by hand too, using your favorite method. You can compute $\det \begin{pmatrix} 1 - \lambda & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 - \lambda & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$, but doing the same for the original matrix would take about the same time.

Comment: Dumb question for you @Alex, how do you know its a rank 1 matrix again?

Comment: @Shammy all the lines are multiples of each other!

Comment: The above matrix didn't work. I ended up getting $\det(A) = -x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x$

Comment: I'm about to give up. How is my determinant wrong ? I Just don't understand I literally just computed the determinant of that matrix with all the 1s

Comment: @Shammy That's not correct. (We're talking about the determinant in my comment, right?) You should get $3\lambda^2  - \lambda^3$. Check your computations.

Comment: @Shammy Also maybe get some rest. You sound very tired!

Comment: I got: $(1-\lambda)[(1 - \lambda)(1 - \lambda) - 1] - 1[1 - \lambda - 1] + 1[1 - 1 - \lambda] = (1 - \lambda)[-2\lambda + \lambda^2] = -2\lambda + \lambda^2 + 2\lambda^2 - \lambda^3 = -2\lambda + 3\lambda^2 - \lambda^3$

Comment: @Shammy The third term should be $1[1-1+\lambda]$ and not $1[1-1-\lambda]$.

Comment: I'm so damn stupid. Thanks for hanging with me lol @Alex